# I want to know if I have done this excercise on parametric equations correctly.

Tags: calculus, parametric

I was solving the following parametric equation:
$$r(t)=(x(t);y(t))=(sin^2 (t), cos(t))  t \varepsilon [0; 2 \pi )$$

I thought that I could do this so I could eliminate the parameter:

$$1=sin^2 (t) + cos^2 (t)$$
$$1-cos^2 (t)=sin^2 (t)$$
$$1-y^2 =x$$

The excercise asks for the orientation of the curve.

So if I graph $y(t)$ I get the cosine function. So from 0 to $\pi$ the function dicreases and from $\pi$ to $2 \pi$ the function increases, which means that the particle has two movements. Then, I can graph the $x(y)$ that I got from the Pythagorean identity, which is a quadratic function. 
Then, putting $t$ values in x and y equations, the first point ($t=0$) tells me that the particle in in $(0,1)$; the second point ($t= \pi $) tells me that it is in $(0;-1)$; the third point is in $t=\pi$, which is equal to the second one; and the fourth point ($t=2 \pi$) tells me that the particle is in $(0;1)$.

Hence, $x(y)$ is just a piece of the whole function, which goes from 1 to -1 in the y axis, and then from -1 to 1.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The particle moves from $(0,1)$ to $(0,-1)$ and then back to $(0,1)$ along the same path.

Comment: I want to know if I have done it correctly

Comment: Because you do not have a closed curve, I don't think we can ask about orientation.

Comment: But you told me that it goes from $(0;1)$ to $(0,-1)$, and then to $(0;1)$. Wouldn't this be the orientation?

Comment: You have to ask yourself what the definition of orientation is.  I suppose you could say that it is negatively oriented from $t = 0 \to \pi$ and positively oriented from $t = \pi \to 2\pi$.

Comment: Oh, great. So, apart from that, the particle moves from (0,1) to (0,-1) and then to (0,1). Doesn't it?